# Use Shell.Application to print PDF to a coded output path (in VBA)

Tags: vba, shell

I'm using this code in VBA (Excel) to print a pdf document (to flatten fields) but I want to avoid the 'Save Print Output As' box that pops up and instead set the output file path in my code.  I've done a lot of searching but not found a solution.

```
Sub PrintToPDF(ByVal inputPath As String, outputPath As String)
    ' Print a PDF file to Microsoft Print to PDF
   
    Dim printerName As String
    printerName = "Microsoft Print to PDF"

    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName(inputPath).invokeverb ("Print")
    
    'Desired outcome: Save to "outputPath"

End Sub
```

The unwanted output dialogue box that comes up upon executing the code:
[image: Save Print Output As dialogue box]

Any pointers gratefully received.  I use Foxit Phantom 10.1 and an open to other methods of printing or flattening the pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the useful pointers @KJ, I'll get researching. I did look for Foxit guidance on command line options but couldn't find anything.